# Qt : Software using QOpenGLWidget crash on mainwindow.show()

Tags: c++, linux, qt, opengl, crash

I'm having issue with using QOpenGLWidget. As soon as I try to compile then run a program using QOpenGLWidget, it crashes ( segmentation fault ) when attempting to call mainwindow.show() in the main.cpp file.

This also happens in Qt examples.

Strangely, replacing QOpenGLWidget with QGLWidget, program starts up fine (but I did not test any further)

I'm using Qt5.5.1 (from ubuntu repo) on Linux Mint 18.

Any idea what might happen here?

Comment: Post some code, it's very hard to help without it

Comment: Have a look at any Qt examples using QOpenGlWidget, p.ex : http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtopengl-cube-example.html. Any of thoses get the same issue

Comment: What's the callstack of the segmentation fault?

Comment: Please post an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Also, I don't quite understand you comment about the Qt examples.  Are you saying that the examples provided by Qt display the same problem?

Comment: Qt examples were indeed displying the same problem. I had the wrong qmake package installed

Answer (score 0):

Got it fixed !
Instead of qt5-qmake, I had the qt5-qmake-gles package installed on my computer. Removing it, and replacing it by qt5-qmake made everything work as expected